# unable to retrieve bundle on activity restart: app acts as if the bundle didnt exist

Tags: android

Problem: When user starts the game, he is given 6 words to choose from, these 6 words are randomly chosen from a list. However, every time the user closes this activity and then re-open it again, a different set of six words appear.

This is what I tried to remedy this problem:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {
    protected static ArrayList<String> mSavedList;
    protected TextView word1;
    protected LinkedList<String> mCopy;
    protected TextView word2;
     /// all the way to word6

    @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mSavedList = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("savedList");

         word1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word1);
         word1.setText(mSavedList.get(1));

        word2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word2);
        word2.setText(mSavedList.get(2));
         //up until word6

     }

   else {
    //take the list of all the words in the LinkedList mCopy, 
     randomize it, and pick the first         six.

   }

}// end of onCreate method 

  @Override
   public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mSavedList = new ArrayList<String>(mCopy.subList(1, 7));
    savedInstanceState.putStringArrayList("savedList", mSavedList);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

My app does not crash when I run the code, it just continues to behave as if the bundle was not created. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Hi What i see your declare the array list as static. If array list is static then reopen the application then sure you get the same array as user see in first time. If application is no longer in background or in memory then you can recreate the new random number again,

Comment: can you put non-static array in bundle and then try ! I am sure it will work

Comment: Do you mean change mSavedList to non-static? i tried that and it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I edit the code let's take the look below

> mSavedList = new ArrayList(mCopy.subList(1, 7));

The random number can only generate if savedInstanceState is null.
One more remove the static from arrray list make it normal

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {
    protected ArrayList<String> mSavedList;
    protected TextView word1;
    protected LinkedList<String> mCopy;
    protected TextView word2;
     /// all the way to word6

    @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mSavedList = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("savedList");

         word1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word1);
         word1.setText(mSavedList.get(1));

        word2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word2);
        word2.setText(mSavedList.get(2));
         //up until word6

     }

   else {
    //take the list of all the words in the LinkedList mCopy, 
     randomize it, and pick the first         six.
        mSavedList = new ArrayList<String>(mCopy.subList(1, 7));
   }

}// end of onCreate method 

  @Override
   public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putStringArrayList("savedList", mSavedList);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but unfortunately everytime I the open the game activity, different words still continue to appear

Comment: So what do you want. Every time when you open the app the same number it should display.

Comment: I want every time the user opens the game activity, the same words appear that appear the first time. 
So when the user first starts the game against a new player, he is given four random words. Now if before the game is  over, the user has to close the game , when he comes back to it, the same words appear

Comment: ok then you have to use the storage options for save that array and use it again when user open the activity. The reason we can not use the static variable the static lifetime is up to process. if the process is not longer then the variable might be not available. So kindly please store in db or preference and reuse it for next time when open the activitity.

Comment: Another best options is convert the user selected options arrylist into the json string and store into the preference.  Again when you want to retrieve it convert the json string to arraylist.

Comment: Are you using the android studios or eclipse ?

Comment: I am using android studio. I will save the data on the SQLite database and let you know the result(and check your  answer). Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Sure let's perform it.

Comment: I am sorry, I should have provided an update, but I am stuck with a more basic problem related to this question. I posted a new question about it, please have a look if you can. 

Once that problem is solved, I plan on implementing your solution to this problem.

Comment: Hello, I have done as you suggested, created an sqlite database to store my data. I have made a separate question about the problem I am facing now, please have a look if you are able to. Thank you!

Comment: Share with me the post link here. I will check it and try to help you :)

Comment: Hello, please see the following 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959720/unable-to-display-data-from-sqlite-database-in-android)