# unable to display data from SQLite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

**Background**: I am creating a turnbased multiplayer game. The user is randomly matched with another user. Upon matching, the user is given a list of words, which he will need to use for the reminder of the game. This list of words is randomly chosen from a much larger list.

The relevant classes are:

`WordsListDatabaseHelper` - contains table which saves the opponent name, and the randomized list of words.

`FindingOpponentActivity` - Opponent is found and randomly matched with user.

`PlayGameActivity`- the wordList is retrieved from the database and put here.

`WordList`- class that contains a long list of words, has a static `getRandomWords` method that returns a sublist.

**Problem**: Once the user is matched with another in the FindOpponentActivity, an intent is fired up and a new activity PlayGameActivity, starts. This is the activity where the random list of words is suppose to appear but the area where they are suppose to be is empty. There are no exceptions thrown, the logcat has no weird output to my knowledge.

I set breakpoints on this line of code:

`WordsListDatabaseHelper.insertWordList (db, wordsContainer, mOpponent.getUsername());`
On debugging, I got the following message: warning: no executable code found in line(this line number)

I also put additional breakpoints on this block of code in `PlayGameActivity`:

```
  if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            //get wordList
            String savedWordList  = cursor.getString(0);

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
            ArrayList<String> finalWordList = gson.fromJson(savedWordList, type);
            mCopy = new LinkedList<String>();
            mCopy.addAll(finalWordList);
```

There were no messages here, but when I double clicked on `finalWordList` or `savedWordList` I got the following message: cannot find local variable `savedWordList/finalWordList`. 
furthermore, when I double click on mCopy, it shows: mCopy = null;

Here are the relevant codes:

```
public class WordsListDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

protected static Set<String> mSelectedWords;
private static final String DB_NAME = "GAME_TABLE";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
protected static LinkedList<String> mCopy;
public static String oppName = "";
protected static String EXTRA_OPPONENT_NAME = "OPPONENT_NAME";


WordsListDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE GAME ("
                    + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + "SELECTED_WORDS TEXT, "
                    + "OPPONENT_NAME TEXT);"

WordsListDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE GAME ("
                    + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + "SELECTED_WORDS TEXT, "
                    + "OPPONENT_NAME TEXT);"
    );


   public static void insertWordList(SQLiteDatabase db, String wordsContainer, String oppName) {
    ContentValues wordValues = new ContentValues();

    wordValues.put("SELECTED_WORDS", wordsContainer);
    wordValues.put("OPPONENT_NAME", oppName);
    db.insert("GAME", null, wordValues);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
 }
```

}

This is from `FindingOpponentActivity`, in the `onResume` method:

```
 //add the game values in the SQLite database
                    String wordsContainer = new String();
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    wordsContainer = gson.toJson(WordsList.getRandomWords());

                    SQLiteOpenHelper wordsListDatabaseHelper =
                            new WordsListDatabaseHelper(FindingOpponentActivity.this);

                    SQLiteDatabase db = wordsListDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                    WordsListDatabaseHelper.insertWordList
                            (db, wordsContainer, mOpponent.getUsername());
```

Finally, here is the code from the `onCreate` method of `PlayGameActivity`:

```
 Intent randIntent = getIntent();
    mOpponentName = randIntent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_RAND_OPPONENT);
    try {
        SQLiteOpenHelper wordsListDatabaseHelper = new WordsListDatabaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = wordsListDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query("GAME",
                new String[] {"SELECTED_WORDS"},
                "OPPONENT_NAME =? ",
                new String[]{mOpponentName},
                null, null, null);

        //move to the first record in the Cursor

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            //get wordList
            String savedWordList  = cursor.getString(0);

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
            ArrayList<String> finalWordList = gson.fromJson(savedWordList, type);

            protected LinkedList<String> mCopy;
            mCopy = new LinkedList<String>();
            mCopy.addAll(finalWordList);
```

I know this is a very lengthy post, but I will be eternally grateful for any sort of help. I have been stuck on this problem for an embarrassingly long period of time.

**Update No.1:** As per __ suggestion, I have tried the following: 
- Deleting and re-installing the app apk
- Cleaning and rebuilding the entire project

I have also put log messages here:

```
try {

          WordsListDatabaseHelper.insertWordList
              (db, wordsContainer, mOpponent.getUsername());
            }

catch(SQLiteException e1) {
        Log.i(TAG, e1.getMessage());
            }
```

No messages were logged.

Comment: " warning: no executable code found in line(this line number" means your code is out of sync. uninstall the apk manually, clean and rebuild each of the modules/libraries and then the entire project and try again.

Comment: I did exactly as you suggested, but nothing changed

Comment: This is very interesting indeed. Did you try putting to log statements on either side of that line?

Comment: No I didn't. How would I go about creating a log statement in this case? (My only experience with log statements is in try/catch scenarios).

Comment: as described here. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html then you will be able to see the log in logcat

Comment: Please see the update.

Comment: there are several libraries that you can add to your app to explore the content of your database to see what has actually been saved.

Comment: sprinkle logs liberally see what gets called and what doesn't. Is the first code dump correct? (there are two onCreate s in it)